# Photon PUN2 Unity3D - Sending RPC works on Standalone (PC), but not on Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have two RPC calls sent from GameManager

PUNPlayerManager.LocalPlayerInstance.GetComponent().SetDuelGameRPC(duelGameString);
    PUNPlayerManager.LocalPlayerInstance.GetComponent().SetInGameRPC(true);

```
On the player instance:





    public void SetDuelGameRPC(string duelGame) //To be called by masterClient
    {
      photonView.RPC("SetInGame", RpcTarget.All, duelGame);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void SetDuelGame(string duelGame)
    {
      Debug.Log("received gameString " + duelGame);

      this.duelGameString = duelGame;

    }

    public void SetInGameRPC(bool inGame) //To be called by masterClient
    {
      photonView.RPC("SetInGame", RpcTarget.All, inGame);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void SetInGame(bool inGame)
    {
      this.inGame = inGame;
    }
```

The good: Everything works fine on standalone (PC) build

The bad: On android emulator and Unity Editor;

1. The first call SetDuelGameRPC seems to be ignored
2. I get the following error for both players

PhotonView with ID 1001 has no method "SetInGame" that takes 1 argument(s): String
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:ExecuteRpc(Hashtable, Player) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:507)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:RPC(PhotonView, String, RpcTarget, Player, Boolean, Object[]) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:1233)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:RPC(PhotonView, String, RpcTarget, Boolean, Object[]) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetwork.cs:2668)
Photon.Pun.PhotonView:RPC(String, RpcTarget, Object[]) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:415)
PUNPlayerManager:SetDuelGameRPC(String) (at Assets/Scripts/PUN/PUNPlayerManager.cs:101)
GameManager:PrepareDuelGame() (at Assets/Scripts/PUN/GameManager.cs:131)
GameManager:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/PUN/GameManager.cs:162)

Comment: Please ask questions regarding games on the [Game Developer community](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: Please ask questions regarding games on the [Game Developer community](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void SetInGameRPC(bool inGame) //To be called by masterClient
{
     var _photonView = this.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
     _photonView.RPC("SetInGame", RpcTarget.All, inGame);
}
```

Try this code

I think the photonView variable in the PUNPlayerManager is incorrectly specified.